# Downloading Flowplayer Videos With Authentication

Tags: java, video, flowplayer

My University has uploaded lecture videos on their website. To access them, certain credentials have to be entered which I obviously possess. They are using a simple [Apache Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server). Videos are embedded as [`Flowplayer`](https://flowplayer.org/) and they do not provide a means of downloading them. The `html` source of the video page is roughly the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Show video</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.com/videos/javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.example.com/videos/css/mta.css?timestamp=1440967823" />
</head>
<body>
<script src="javascript/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; background-color: #ff00ff" id="player"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$f("player", "javascript/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", {
    onLoad: function(){
        $.get("https://www.example.com/videos/prepareVideo",
                {videoID :'fae98609a52e6d252606248d1339e919'},
                function(data){
                                        $f("player").play(data.url);
                                        $('#player').width(data.width);
                                        $('#player').height(data.height);
                                        $('#title').html("Playing "+data.description);
                }
           );
    }
}
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried observing the network tab in the Chrome developer tools and it revealed the location of the video due to the highest network consumption. It is called `video.mp4`.

Opening its url in the browser returns a page with the following contents:

```
<html><body>404 File not found, no session data found</body></html>
```

Why does it not find the file? What's the deal with the session data? I authenticated myself. Is there a way to get the video and download it programmatically via its direct download link though assuming one can supply the credentials?

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this information is still helpful for you, but the
following short script does the trick:

```
#!/bin/sh
vid="$1";

user="youknowit";
pass="youknowit";

file="cookies.txt"
opts="--load-cookies=$file --save-cookies=$file --keep-session-cookies";
prep="https://www.example.com/the-real-fsID/prepareVideo?videoID=$vid";

raw="$(wget $opts --user=$user --password=$pass -qO - $prep)";
echo $raw;
url="$(echo $raw | grep '"url":"' | sed 's/.*"url":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/g;s/\\//g')";
tag="$(echo $raw | grep '"description":"' | sed 's/.*"description":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/g;s/\\//g')";
echo $url;
wget $opts --user=$user --password=$pass -O "$tag".mp4 "$url";
echo "done!";
```

Actually, the sole purpose of the http-server's credentials used
here is to authenticate you. But the next steps are the really
important ones. The site uses session-cookies to keep track of
your request on the video. The "perpareVideo"-script is actually
a php-script, that - as far as I could figure out - is creating
a temporary file on the server that is only present while you're
playing the video. The file seems to become invalid if too much
time elapses between the preparation and the download request.

So two consecutive http-requests are necessary to "see" the real
video file. I realized this with two runs of the wget-tool. The
"bonus" here is, that the file even gets its real name (tag) out
of the meta-information gathered with the first http-request.

The most important thing is, that the two requests shall belong
to the same session, the rest is easy ;)

I think they invested a good amount of time in building up this
video infrastructure and even more in avoiding a download of the
videos, but the funny thing is, the lecture is about "security"
which also covers "availability", so the videos there should be
(at least in my opinion) available even when one is not able to
access the internet, the content should be provided barrier-free.
So, since some of the content is only available as videos, there
is the need to download this content the same way as it can be
done with the pdf-files.

Best wishes ...